# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies. Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list

Tags: android, eclipse, dependencies, android-support-library

In my existing project i want to add ActionBar for older versions less than api-11. So i imported **android-support-v7-appcompact** with resources following [the official site](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).Till here every thing works fine. When i extended ActionBarActivity to my MainActivity.java the following [error occurred in console, please see the screen shot](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/d61e8ab7-516f-4c48-8e7d-e35e4e624370/2d9f547de1ef43065fdb83c673838a5e).

```
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:maxSdkVersion="19"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

Project Build Target is 4.1.2 . Java Compiler is set to 1.6. I am also using facebook sdk in my project, so i deleted **android-support-v4.jar** file from the project **libs** folder but error did not go. Finally clean and build the project. Any suggestions PLEASE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is telling you that you have two android-support, one in appcompact and one in the facebook sdk.

Comment: Thanks @Victor_J_Martin , yes i know but what should i do to solve the issue.

Comment: Remove the android-support-v4.jar in your own project (in /libs)

Comment: @Francesco verheye, i have done that already and restarted eclipse but did not slove.

Comment: Try to delete android-support-v4.jar of one of the libs, for example, of the facebook sdk. See Open Java Build Path ->Open Libraries Tab-> Expand all ->Find Duplicate -> Remove Them.

Delete Bin Folder. Clean Project.

Comment: @ Victor_J_Martin, can you tell me which one should i delete from this screen shot http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/423bbe7f-373c-47fa-9625-376ee402dea0/4f2ee9065c28b91be7f1ca36b7e7ef69  if i delete android-support-v4.jar from FacebookSDK errors in FacebookSDK