# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies after creating new project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is my first android application and I have recently installed Eclipse. When I am creating android project I am getting this error. What does it mean and how can I resolve it?

> ```
> [2014-10-27 12:02:01 - App] Path: /Users/adminmac/Documents/workspace/App/libs/android-support-v4.jar
> [2014-10-27 12:02:01 - App]   Length: 987314
> [2014-10-27 12:02:01 - App]   SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
> [2014-10-27 12:02:01 - App] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
> ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710152/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar

Comment: are you using any other library....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your lib

**Right click on your project -> Android Tool -> Add support library**